# Incorrect image size

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

this is how my app should look like:

[image]

But this is how it looks like on a Galaxy S4 (running stock Android 4.2.2)

[image]

The images are displayed much smaller than expected. It seems that the problem is similar to this one: [XML Layout on Sony Smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974245/xml-layout-on-sony-smartwatch) but I've already put my image files in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder, as advised.

I'm loading the drawables like this:

```
phoneTypeMobile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.type_mobile);
```

And displaying them on the screen:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(phoneTypeMobile, 2, height - 20, null);
```

What could be the reason for this problem? Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Use the image button while editing question. Save people following links. The links also don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see your images, but I know what you mean.

Force a density while decoding:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
options.inScaled = false;
phoneTypeMobile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                                               R.drawable.type_mobile,
                                               options);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way, I thought I did accept the answer immediately, sorry for being late.